# Access console logs from php's file_get_content() function

Tags: javascript, php, html, jasmine, bamboo

So I have a simple php file with the following code in it:

```
 $contents = file_get_contents("path/to/file.html");
 var_dump($contents);
```

Within the html file I have a few scripts that run and returns data to console.log. But, when i execute the php command (linux virtual machine) and run the file it just returns the static html content. Whereas when I open the file from the browser, it executes all the javascript files and returns the expected html output with data in console.log. To be specific, the html file executes a jasmine test suite.

So, I would like to know if there is any way to print out the results from the console.log or actually execute the javascript files through a php script and a linux virtual machine. Also, the main purpose is to execute the test via Bamboo, a continuous integration server.

I have tried phantomjs but it results in other errors and I would prefer not to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Simple saying, no, you cannot do that.

The reason is that you need browser to execute javascript, and PHP just does not have browser capable of doing that as efficient as you want. There is CURL, but it cannot run javascript.